# Get request in local not working React Native

Tags: react-native, httprequest

How to correctly send a request to a local network?
Tried this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const test = () => {
  axios.get('http://192.168.0.100/Power?Power=1')
    .then(response => {
      // Success!
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // Error!
    });
};

return (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => test()}>
    <Text>Turn on power</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Everything works well from the browser and the Android emulator, but after compiling the app and installing it on the phone, nothing works, there are no errors. Although API requests to the another site (not on local network) go through without problems.
Help me figure it out please. I am newbie.

Comment: Is your phone and the computer connected to the same network?

Comment: Of course, on the phone from the browser the same request passes smoothly.

Comment: When I use the phone instead of the Android emulator, connected to the computer, everything works well, but when I compile the app and install it on the phone, it no longer works...